# Responsive custom expanding preview

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to build an expanding preview like http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ThumbnailGridExpandingPreview/.

But I need to customize it based on my requirement.

Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nayyarmannu/qprohfst/2/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=qprohfst).

Problems I am facing are:

1. The pointer does not point to the image properly. (it points but hides behind the box)
2. When clicking on first image, all the elements to the right shifts down.

Along with that I would also like to ask, can we fit all the 8 circular div in a single row?

Thank you.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mn").click(function() {
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); //Find the target via the href
    if ($(activeTab).is(':visible')) {
      $(activeTab).slideUp();
      $(this).removeClass("active");
    } else {
      $(".mn").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
      $(this).addClass("active")
      $('.tab').hide();
      $(activeTab).fadeIn();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.mn.active:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -12px;
  margin: 0 0 0 -6px;
  /*width: 0;*/
  /*height: 0;*/
  border-left: 12px solid transparent;
  border-right: 12px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 12px solid red;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 0;
}

.ratio {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.img-circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.mn.active,
.mn:focus {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  outline: none
}

.tab {
  display: none;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 2% 10px 0;
  background: red;
  min-height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab1" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">1</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab">Tab 1</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab2" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">2</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab">Tab 2</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab3" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">3</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab">Tab 3</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab4" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">4</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab">Tab 4</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab5" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">5</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab5" class="tab">Tab 5</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab6" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">6</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab6" class="tab">Tab 6</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab7" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">7</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab7" class="tab">Tab 7</div>

  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <a href="#tab8" class="mn">
      <div class="ratio img-responsive img-circle" style="background-image: url(/img/analytics.png); background-color: #FFC107;"></div>
      <div class="text-center">8</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="tab8" class="tab">Tab 8</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would it be acceptable to put the `col-sm-2` divs inside rows? You can then use the extra row which is 100% width to store all the tabs.

Comment: Regarding your last question: "can we fit all the 8 circular div in a single row." You could use `col-sm-1` instead of `col-sm-2`  to store 8 divs on one row but then it won't stretch 100% across. You can create a modified version of bootstrap that uses 8 columns instead of 12. You can do that here: https://getbootstrap.com/customize/. Just change the @grid-columns setting to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LyL8vkmr/4/

I put each `col-sm-2` inside a `<div class="row"></div>` and I put all the tabs in a separate `<div class="row"></div>`. Now when you click a circle, it opens a tab in the row underneath it and pushes all the circles in the next row. However it still doesn't work perfectly because when you resize it to small size and click on a circle, the tab opens up at the very bottom of the row and you can't see it easily.

Also note I changed `col-sm-2` to `col-sm-1` since you said you wanted 8 divs in a row. The only problem with this is that it doesn't stretch 100% across. If you want 8 columns to stretch all the way across then you need to use a custom version of bootstrap. [Just go here](https://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system) and enter 8 for the @grid-columns field.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew for the solution.

Comment: But @Andrew this design is not responsive. When i am trying to open it in a mobile device, the expanding preview displays at the end. Is there any solution to this?